# Не проходит запрос к контроллеру ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Я добавил новый api контроллер с использование Entity для работы с новой таблицей в БД.
Первый api контроллер работает как надо.
[image: Запрос к первому контроллеру]

Это запрос к первому контроллеру.
А вот его код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestReact.Models;

namespace TestReact.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ChildrenController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ClinicContext _context;

        public ChildrenController(ClinicContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Children
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Child>>> GetChildren()
        {

            var test = _context.Mkb10s.ToList();

            
            return await _context.Children
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutChild(int id, Child child)
        {
            if (id != child.ChildId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ChildExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Children
        //To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Child>> PostChild(Child child)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(child);
            _context.Children.Add(child);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (ChildExists(child.ChildId))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction("GetChild", new { id = child.ChildId }, child);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Children/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteChild(int id)
        {
            var child = await _context.Children.FindAsync(id);
            if (child == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Children.Remove(child);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool ChildExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Children.Any(e => e.ChildId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

А вот запрос ко второму контроллеру
[image: Запрос ко второму контроллеру]

Его код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestReact.Models;

namespace TestReact.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class Mkb10Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ClinicContext _context;

        public Mkb10Controller(ClinicContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Mkb10
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Mkb10>>> GetMkb10s()
        {
          if (_context.Mkb10s == null)
          {
              return NotFound();
          }
            return await _context.Mkb10s.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Mkb10/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Mkb10>> GetMkb10(int id)
        {
          if (_context.Mkb10s == null)
          {
              return NotFound();
          }
            var mkb10 = await _context.Mkb10s.FindAsync(id);

            if (mkb10 == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return mkb10;
        }

        // PUT: api/Mkb10/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutMkb10(int id, Mkb10 mkb10)
        {
            if (id != mkb10.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(mkb10).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!Mkb10Exists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Mkb10
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Mkb10>> PostMkb10(Mkb10 mkb10)
        {
          if (_context.Mkb10s == null)
          {
              return Problem("Entity set 'ClinicContext.Mkb10s'  is null.");
          }
            _context.Mkb10s.Add(mkb10);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (Mkb10Exists(mkb10.Id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction("GetMkb10", new { id = mkb10.Id }, mkb10);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Mkb10/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteMkb10(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Mkb10s == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var mkb10 = await _context.Mkb10s.FindAsync(id);
            if (mkb10 == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Mkb10s.Remove(mkb10);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool Mkb10Exists(int id)
        {
            return (_context.Mkb10s?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

И код Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestReact.Models;
using TestReact.Controllers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

string connection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

//builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ClinicContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");


app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с маршрутизацией.
[microsoft doc 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#binding-source-parameter-inference)
[microsoft doc 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В целом, ответ не должен состоять из фактически только ссылок, т.к. если содержимое по ссылке будет перемещено или удалено, ответ станет бесполезен.